# Linux loading i2c drivers

Tags: linux, driver, i2c

I have linux 4.4 on my board. I also have two i2c devices with their driver.
When I connect first device to board - i see in dmesg that _probe function called. 
When I don't connect any device to board - in dmesg i don't see _probe function. 
When I connect second device - in dmesg i don't see _probe function. But I want to see it. 
If I use i2cdetect tool i see correct device addresses. Field .detect in driver don't used. I want to see _probe function in dmesg with second device or without devices.

How linux check connected i2c devices and how it choose will driver load or not?

This my device tree:

```
    i2c@546c0000 {
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;
        compatible = "nvidia,tegra210-vii2c";
        reg = <0x0 0x546c0000 0x0 0x34000>;
        iommus = <0x52 0x12>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x11 0x4>;
        scl-gpio = <0x7b 0x92 0x0>;
        sda-gpio = <0x7b 0x93 0x0>;
        status = "okay";
        clocks = <0x41 0xd0 0x41 0x51 0x41 0x1c>;
        clock-names = "vii2c", "i2cslow", "host1x";
        resets = <0x41 0xd0>;
        reset-names = "vii2c";
        clock-frequency = <0x61a80>;
        bus-pullup-supply = <0x69>;
        avdd_dsi_csi-supply = <0x67>;
        linux,phandle = <0xe0>;
        phandle = <0xe0>;

        newname_c@30 {
            compatible = "nvidia,newname";
            reg = <0x30>;
            devnode = "video0";
            physical_w = "3.674";
            physical_h = "2.738";
            vertical-flip = "true";
            avdd-reg = "vana";
            iovdd-reg = "vif";
            clocks = <0x41 0x117>;
            clock-names = "clk_out_3";
            clock-frequency = <0x16e3600>;
            mclk = "clk_out_3";
            reset-gpios = <0x7b 0x94 0x0>;
            pwdn-gpios = <0x7b 0x97 0x0>;
            vana-supply = <0x94>;
            vif-supply = <0x93>;
            status = "okay";
            linux,phandle = <0xe1>;
            phandle = <0xe1>;
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices

Comment: Thank you, i read this document many times. May be you can tell me what lines in my device tree are checking is i2c-device connected to my board or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During he boot process, when the kernel parses the device tree and reaches your device node, it will look for any driver with an `of_match_table` whose one of the `compatible` entries match your node's `compatible` property. Each matched driver will be loaded, its `probe` function will be run and given a suitable `struct i2c_client` structure as parameter, according to (and containing) elements you specified in your node (I skipped the details).
So to answer to your question, Linux (the I2C core actually) **does not** check any connected i2c device. The corresponding device driver does (in the `probe` function generally, usually by reading a register whose value is known in advance). This is why you have to declare your device in advance. Have [a look here](http://labcsmart.fr/en/tutorial/brief-introduction-to-linux-device-and-driver-model/#esd) for details on devices and drivers matching, as well as module auto-loading.

First, try to make sure the support of your driver has been enabled in the kernel
config using the below command:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep <your_driver_kconfig_option>
```

You should see something ending with `=y` or `=m`.
Now, back to your issue, there are several reasons why this may not work:

- Your driver is not built or not installed (if built as module)
- The driver does not have this compatible entry in its `of_match_table`. You
  can try a match with the driver's name (the compatible value of your node should be the same as `i2c_driver.driver.mame` element in the driver code). This is not clean but may help.

PS: If the `/proc/config.gz` file does not exist, run `modprobe configs` command first.